# JavaScript + HTML5 Audio Player - Stop Buffering, EventHandler Issues

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I've written some javascript so that the player will stop buffering once its paused so it will stop buffering. The code basically destroys the player, creates a new one, every time either play or pause is pressed. My only problem is it seems that it only listens for the play or pause event once. If I do them again, the code no longer runs. Can someone PLEASE take a look at this and let me know what I did wrong? Before you ask, the reason I'm recreating the player is because I hear this is necessary to do for ios to actually stop buffering.. Is this true? If there is a better way please let me know, as any help would be appreciated.

Thanks! (Code Below)

```
<audio id="myaudio" controls>
  <source id="sourceMp3" src="" autoplay type="audio/mp3" preload="none"/>
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<script type="text/javascript">
var sourceMp3=document.getElementById('myaudio');
sourceMp3.src="url of mp3 stream";

function playfunc(){
    var audio = document.getElementById('myaudio');
    //audio.pause(0);
    audio.src = "http://";
    audio.load();
    audio.remove();
    var x = document.createElement("AUDIO");
    x.setAttribute("id","myaudio");
    x.setAttribute("controls", "controls");
    x.setAttribute("src","http://");
    x.load();
    document.body.appendChild(x);
    var audio = document.getElementById('myaudio');
    audio.src = "http://";
    audio.load();
    audio.src = "url of mp3 stream";
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
    console.log('play pressed')
}


function pausefunc(){
    //var tmp = sourceMp3.src;
    var audio = document.getElementById('myaudio');
    audio.pause(0);
    audio.src = "http://";
    audio.load();
    audio.remove();
    var x = document.createElement("AUDIO");
    x.setAttribute("id","myaudio");
    x.setAttribute("controls", "controls");
    x.setAttribute("src","http://");
    x.load();
    document.body.appendChild(x);
    var audio = document.getElementById('myaudio');
    audio.src = "http://";
    audio.load();
    audio.src = "url of mp3 stream";
    audio.load();
    audio.pause();
    console.log('pause pressed');

}


document.getElementById('myaudio').addEventListener('pause', pausefunc, false);
document.getElementById('myaudio').addEventListener('play', playfunc, false);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment out your code and just log the click.  Something is triggering an exception killing the event.  You'll see it the event fires reliably without your code.